# ¿Cómo puedo instertar un <script> dinámicamente en otra parte del documento a pesar de no tener acceso a esa parte?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy dando estilos a una *landing page* dentro de una plataforma, por tal motivo no tengo acceso al documento de la *landing page*, entonces no puedo manipular todo el DOM de forma convencional, por lo cual ocupo agregar el `<script>` hasta el final del documento para poder darle estilo a ciertos elementos a los cuales no tengo acceso a ellos para modificarlos directamente y por otras caracteristicas que requieren que tenga que hacer tal "maniobra". NOTA: No puedo subir el script a otra pagina para luego hacer un `appendChild` con el `src` del *script*. De forma explicita, tengo un `<div>` que contiene unos botones los cuales estan localizados por defecto abajo de un elemento, sin embargo estos botones deberian de estar ubicados sobre tal elemento. Lo que hice fue duplicar el codigo de los botones hasta donde yo puedo manipularlos. Entonces por tal motivo decido hacer un codigo que agarre todos los elementos con la misma clase para esconder el ultimo (hablando del div de los botones, el que viene por defecto en la plataforma y es mismo que yo duplique copiandolo del codigo fuente) he aqui el codigo. Entonces el script tag ocupo ponerlo casi hasta el final del documento para que el `getElementsByClassName` agarre todos los que tengan la clase de button-group y puedo ocultar el ultimo.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="div-prueba">
        <button>Hola</button>
        <button>Bye</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("div-prueba");
        x[1].style.display = "none";
    </script>
    <!--NO TENGO ACCESO A ESTA PARTE DEL DOCUMENTO-->
    <div class="div-prueba">
        <button>Hola</button>
        <button>Bye</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

O sea que lo que se ejecuta dentro de `<script>` hasta ese punto solo encuentra un elemento con la clase de "div-prueba", logicamente tendria que ponerlo hasta despues del ultimo elemento con esa clase para que cuando se guarden dentro del arreglo de la variable `x` Puedo ahora si elegir el que yo quiero que no se muestre, es decir el ultimo, y como son dos pues seria el que esta en la posicion 1 del arreglo. O sea que ocupo hacer un script para que inserte el script de

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("div-prueba");
    x[1].style.display = "none";
</script>
```

despues de la linea comentada, seguido del ultimo `div` con clase "div-prueba"

Comment: podrias agregar mas info, digamos tomas un elemento y dices que quieres hacer, asi como lo que haz intentado.

Comment: Listo ya he añadido mas informacion

Comment: No sé si es porque no has usado el punto y aparte, el hecho es que no entendí tu pregunta. Quizá si expones el problema resumido en un primer párrafo y luego explicas los detalles en párrafos subsiguientes con sus debidos puntos y aparte, se entendería mejor.

Comment: Que tal A. Cedano. Ya agregue un codigo analogo con el que estoy trabajando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tenés acceso al DOM, tenés acceso a cualquier parte del DOM expuesta **antes** que tu etiqueta `<script>`. Lo que tenés que hacer para obtener acceso a uno o más elementos cargados después de tu etiqueta `<script>`, es esperar a que el documento haya terminado de cargarse.

El siguiente código realiza exactamente eso, al esperar a que el evento `"load"` se dispare:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    // Tu código acá
});
```